# Computing power of AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpu, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a CPU-intensive application that I'm considering hosting on 1+ AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances. If at all possible, I'd like to throttle it so that I don't dip over the "free" utilization of the instances.

So I need to figure out what kind of hardware/virtualized hardware the Beanstalk instances are running on, and compare that to the maximum CPU utilization of the free versions.

So for instance, if each Beanstalk instance is running on, say, 2GHz CPUs, and my app performs a specific "supercalc" operation that takes 50 million CPU operations, but the free version of the app only allows me to utilize 100 billion operations per day, then I am limited to 100billion/50million = 2,000 "supercalcs" per day on a free instance. So if the CPU is 2GHz, then my app instance could only run for 2GHz/50million = 40 seconds before I've already "maxed out" the free CPU utilization on the Beanstalk instance.

This is probably not a great example, but hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to achieve. I need to figure out how much I need to throttle my app, or how long my app could run before I max out the Beanstalk CPU utilization, and it really comes down to how beefy the AWS Beanstalk machines are. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are looking for hardware configurations of the Beanstalk machines, it uses EC2 instances. You can choose type of instance before launching the environment. You can find configuration of instances at http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 instances aren't based on a "CPU utilisation" billing system (I think Google App Engine is?) - EC2 instance billing is based on the amount of time the machine is "on" regardless of what is doing.  See the [Amazon EC2 Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) for the amount it costs to run the different instances sizes in different regions.

There is a special case which is the "Micro" instance - this provides the ability to have short bursts of higher CPU usage than the "small" instance at a lower cost, but if you overuse it you get throttled back for a period (which you don't with a Small).  This isn't the same as having an operation limit though, and the price remains the same whether you're throttled or not.

Also note that with Elastic Beanstalk you're also paying for the [Elastic Loadbalancer](http://aws.amazon.com/pricing/elasticloadbalancing/), any storage and bandwidth, and also any database service you are using.

Given all that though - AWS *does* have a [Free Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) - however this is only for the first 12 months of a new account. The Free Tier will cover the cost of a micro EC2 instance, Elastic Loadbalancer, RDS database and other ancillary services - see the link for more info.